# Unable to click parameters tab in Jmeter 5.2.1

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to pass an authorization header along with a request body to an HTTP request in Jmeter. When i pass a parameterized body, I am not able to click on the parameters tab to pass a header, and if I add the header first, the body data tab becomes non-clickable. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters are being used for the [URL Parameters](https://support.clickmeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/211032666-URL-parameters-How-to-pass-it-to-the-destination-URL) or for the [Query String](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).

Use [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to pass an authorization header along with your request body in JMeter.

Just right click on your HTTP sampler and then add HTTP Header Manager from the config element.

In Header Manager, You can add multiple header information along with the request.

[image]